# Are all endomorphisms of C^* just power maps?

Tags: gr.group-theory

If an endomorphism of $\mathbb{C}^*$ is assumed to be holomorphic, then it is not difficult to show that it must be of the form $z^n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$.  I was wondering if this is true without any topological or analytic assumptions on the endomorphism.  My intuition says that there should be lots of them, but I'm usually working with endomorphisms which are at least holomorphic if not a true morphism of varieties, so I'm not sure.

Comment: $C^\times$ is isomorphic as a group to $S^1\times\mathbb R$, and $\mathbb R$, as any infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$, has lots of endomorphisms as an abelian group!

Comment: Although I think you mean $R_{>0}$, I see what you're saying, so thanks for the help!

Comment: No, I mean $\mathbb R$, just because the multiplicative group $\mathbb R_{>0}$ and the additive group $\mathbb R$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't know what group structure you were using.  

Comment: @HNuer: Well, you did not specify yourselves the kind of structure on $\mathbf C^*$ for which you wanted to determine the endomorphisms.

Comment: @HNuer: This very old question has come up in other forums like math.stackexchange.com, and I'm not convinced it's "research-level". Anyway, the elementary expository article linked by Chris is a good standard source (though I'm prejudiced by the fact that Paul Yale was an undergraduate teacher of mine). Like other MAA publications, it usually requires JSTOR access.

Comment: All continuous endomorphisms are of the form $z\mapsto z^n\bar z^m$, for some $n,m \in \mathbb Z$. 

Comment: @Andreas, why is that?  I've heard this before and I can easily prove the holomorphic case, but I can't think off the top of my head why the continuous result is true.

Comment: I know this question is old, but the comment above by @AndreasThom is wrong: all the continous endomorphisms are of the form $|z|^\alpha z^n$ for $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. This is not hard to prove using the isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong \mathbb{R}\times S^1$

Comment: @DenisNardin: You are right, my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

There are many "wild" automorphisms of the complex numbers, that preserve addition and multiplication, but not much else. These are hard to write down, however, as their existence seems to rely on the axiom of choice. See e.g. the great expository paper "[Automorphisms of the complex numbers](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689301)" by P. Yale, Mathematics Magazine 39(3), 1966.